# java double precision error when adding and subtracting the same number

Tags: java, precision

Due to floating point inaccuracies, java's double cannot represent every decimal number exactly, i.e. precision errors are introduced.
Given the following code:

```
double d1=0.20976190476190476;
double d2=0.062142857142857146;
System.out.println("d1-d1= "+(d1-d1)); //Prints 0.0.
System.out.println("d1+d2-d2-d1= "+(d1+d2-d2-d1)); //Prints 2.7755575615628914E-17
```

I'm curious how the last line could produce a precision error? I would assume that the expression is evaluated as: ((d1+d2)-d2)-d1. So even if d1, d2, or (d1+d2) are not represented exactly, I would assume that the precision errors would cancel each other out?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're confused about how IEEE754 floating point math works (this is how `double` and `float` behave in java - according to the IEEE754 spec). That's.. not surprising; it is quite a complicated system, all told!

There are a few easy to understand mental models that should help. Once you know these, you should be able to intuit the answer to your question.

### Remember, computers are decimal

I have a challenge for you. Grab a small piece of paper and write down, in decimal notation, the value of 1 divided by 5. This should be easy, you just write down "0.2" and you're done.

Now flip it over and write down 1 divided by 3.

You can't do it. You can try to get close, depending on the size of your piece of paper you end up with "0.333333333333333" but then you run out of room. It doesn't matter how large your paper is, *given the restriction that you must write it down in decimal and not as a fraction*, you cannot do the job.

So what's so special about 3 versus 5?

The trick is, 5 is a common factor of the base we use in decimal: 5 is divisible by 10, and the decimal system is base 10. For the same reason, 1/2 works (0.5), and even 3/4 works (When you break four down into prime factors, it is `2*2` - and *all* of those are cleanly divisible by 10, our base. That's why 3/4ths 'works' in decimal perfectly). But 1/7 does not work just like 1/6 doesn't work (6 broken down is `2*3` - that 3 isn't cleanly divisible into 10, so, you can't write 1/6th cleanly in decimal).

Computers count in binary though, which immediately results in a nasty surprise: The only common factor in decimal is 2 itself. So, IEEE754 math can accurately represent e.g. 1/8 or even 7/4096, but it's quite limited. 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9, even 1/10 does not work. Only multiples of 2 'work' without errors in decimal. We can trivially observe this:

```
double x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) x += 0.1;
System.out.println(1.0 == x); // prints 'false'. What the....???
```

Try the same chicanery with e.g. `0.75` and you can never get wonky results as 0.25 also works out perfectly well in IEEE754.

In other words, "0.1" (1/10th) works great in our decimal system but in binary it's as problematic as 1/3rd is in decimal: We run out of 'room' on our piece of paper, so the computer has to round it.

### The number line is biased.

Computers are binary beasts and CPUs love fixed width notions - computers can **only** store zeroes and ones, they can't store anything else, not even how lage things are, so unless an external factor dictates how large things are, computers don't know where to look. When writing numbers on piece of paper we have the digits 0 through 9, but we use more than that: We use a dot for fractional nation (1.75 for example), and we use spacing on the page to indicate where things start and end. Computers don't have any of that, so unless you want to expend zeroes and ones to store how large things are, the easiest way to do things is to just decree that the number is 64-bit. Now we know where to start and stop.

Given 64 bits, you can only represent at most `2^64` unique numbers. That's *a lot* of numbers, but not an infinite amount.

Imagine a number line, from negative infinity to positive infinity. Which is what `double` at least theoretically is capable of representing. There are an infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1, let alone across that number line.

Nevertheless, 0.0000000000% of them can be accurately represented by a double. After all, our double can only represent at most 2^64 numbers whereas our number line has an infinite expanse of them.

So how does `double` work? First, it picks slightly less than 2^64 unique numbers. Imagine we throw that many darts at the number line. We call these 'the blessed numbers' - `double` can *only* represent the darts, not any other number. And then IEEE754 makes a very simple decree: Any number (so, any input, any intermediate result) is always **silently** rounded to the nearest dart.

In other words, if we call `dart(x)` the function that rounds a result to the nearest dart, writing `d1 + d2 - d2 - d1` breaks down to `(((d1 + d2) - d2) - d1)`, which turns into `dart(dart(dart(dart(d1) + dart(d2)) - dart(d2)) - dart(d1))`. *That is a lot of darts!!*

The darts aren't uniformly distributed. In fact, half the darts are very close to 0). As you move away from zero, the distance between any two darts grows bigger and bigger.

At 2^53, the distance between 2 darts starts exceeding 1.0. 2^53? That is a blessed number. In fact, all integers from 0 to 2^53 are blessed. But 2^53 + 1? Not blessed. Let's try it!

```
long a = 2L << 52;
sysout(a); // 9007199254740992

double b = Math.pow(2.0, 53);
sysout(b); // 9.007199254740992E15
sysout((long) b); // 9007199254740992
sysout(a == (long) b); // true
```

So far, so good - the `System.out.println` code prints large doubles in exponential notation but it is exactly correct, as 'cast that back to a long' shows. But now...

```
double c = b + 1;
sysout(c); // 9.007199254740992E15
sysout(b == c); // true - wait what?
```

Adding 1 **did nothing**. b and c are in fact the same value still. `dart(b + 1)` is the same as b because 2^53 really is the closest dart to the result of calculating 2^53+1.

```
double d = b - 1;
sysout(d); // 9.007199254740991E15
sysout(b == d); // false
```

But going one down does work fine.

### Explaining your question

Now we can trivially explain your question:

- Your 2 numbers are rounded to the nearest dart. No problem.
- Then we add darted `d1` and darted `d2` together and this number doesn't perfectly fit on a dart (why would it - it rarely does). So that too is rounded to the nearest dart.
- We then subtract darted `d2` again, and then dart that result. That doesn't get us to the same number. This shouldn't be too surprising - the darts aren't equally distributed - adding d1 and d2 together moves to a 'less dart-dense' area of the number line. Less dart-dense means less accuracy. That sidestep into higher numbers (add d2, then subtract again - in the middle of that, we are in the less dart-dense area) costs us.
- Finally you subtract `d1` from what you have. Given that we are now moving closer to the 0, there are *lots* of darts here, so the dart-rounding doesn't get us back to 0, but gets us to some dart really close to 0.

Sure, in theory java could have gone: Oh, hey, `d1+d2-d2-d1`, I can get rid of `d2-d2`, and then that leaves `d1-d1` and get rid of that too, and that leaves `0`, but that's just not how it works: The java spec clearly says that `+` and `-` are binary operators (not any-amount operators), and they are resolved left-to-right. Java is not a mathematician simplifying formulas on a whiteboard. Java simply does what the spec says it does. Which is to break that down to `(((d1+d2)-d2)-d1)`, and then apply IEEE753 (i.e. round to nearest dart for all the things).

Answer (score 3):

From jshell (interactive java shell):
jshell> d1+d2-d2
$6 ==> 0.2097619047619048

Which does not equal d1, so you can quickly confirm that the errors won’t cancel each other out.

An extreme example for the strange behavior of floating point numbers would be to add a very small amount to a very large one — this addition might not even change the large value, so in general d1 + d2 can be equal to d1, even when d2 is not zero.

Floating point math is tricky, where numeric accuracy is very important make sure you use/understand the algorithm at hand, use libraries written by experts, or use BigDecimal, or other arbitrary precision numbers.